# Core Plot: Change y-axis (Labels and Scale) to plot a new graph

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have one graph correctly plotted in my plotspace and I am trying to plot a second graph triggered by a segmented control button instead of the first one.
 The x-axis (xRange and globalXRange) and their corresponding values between graph 1 and 2 are staying the same, just the corresponding y-axis (scale and labels) are changing. This requires a scale and label change on the y-axis... 
For the first plot I already set:

```
// PLOT RANGE Y-Axis
    self.plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-1.2) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(6.5)];
    self.plotSpace.globalYRange = self.plotSpace.yRange;

// Visibility of Y-Axis
    self.axisSet.yAxis.visibleRange   = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0)
                                                                length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(5)];
```

This is working perfect. 
 
When changing self.plotSpace.yRange and self.plotSpace.grobalYRange with new CPTPlotRanges ( I am doing this in the same way as above inside of my segment - if-else statement) , both: y-axis scales and labels are not changing as desired, w.r.t the new y-axis ranges (should be from 0 - 100 and not still from 0 - 5). Just the minorTicksPerInterval changes properly.

How to do that? BTW: I am not looking for 2 y-axis in the same plot. Any suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `globalYRange` constrains the new values assigned to the `yRange`. Set `globalYRange` to `nil` before changing the `yRange`.

```
self.plotSpace.globalYRange = nil;
self.plotSpace.yRange = newRange;
self.plotSpace.globalYRange = self.plotSpace.yRange;
```

Comment: perfect Eric! the order is important... Works! Thanks a lot. I just found the statement in the class reference: "The global range of the y coordinate to which the yRange is constrained. If non-nil, the yRange and any changes to it will be adjusted so that it always fits within the globalYRange. If nil (the default), there is no constraint on y."